# Set the header to be automatically moved to the right in listView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

This is how it looks like when running the program:

[image: When running]

This is how it looks like when i manually drag the header to the right:

[image: manually]

How can i do it by code to get the second result the manually ?

```
listView1.Scrollable = true;
listView1.View = View.Details;
ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
header.Text = "";
header.Name = "col1";
listView1.Columns.Add(header);

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\countriesandcodes.txt");
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count(); i += 2)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is not about 'moving the header right' but making the 1st column header 'wider', right? Have you tried setting the Width of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your column width is not wide enough to capture the entire text. The method: [ListView.AutoResizeColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.autoresizecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) is made to do exactly this.

```
listView1.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```